# Cannot find substring if the string is too long in pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

Im writing a code that needs to find a substring in a string. 
It works good if the string is short, but for very long list of long strings, it does not work. How can I fix this?

For example, for this code, it works:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'spike-2': ["yesnoyesno", "chairchairchair"],
        'hey spke': ["maybe maybe maybe", "yes no yes"],
        'no': ["aaaaa...VALUE...govora","yesno"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

new_data1 = df1.to_string(header=False,
                  index=False,
                  index_names=False).split('\n')

#print(new_data1)

for i in new_data1:

    if 'VALUE' in i:
        print('found!')
```

But for this code, it does not work:

```
data2 = {'spike-2': ["yesno   yesno yesno  yes  no yesnoyesno yesnoyesno yesnoyesno", "chairchairchair    chairchairchair    chairchairchair   chairchairchair "],
        'hey spke': ["maybe maybe maybe", "yes nyes no ye...VALUE...syes no yesyes no yesyes no yesyes no yeso yes"],
        'no': ["yes no yesyes no yes yesyes yesyes yes no yes  yes no yesaaaaa...VALUE...govora","yesno"]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

new_data2 = df2.to_string(header=False,
                  index=False,
                  index_names=False).split('\n')

print(new_data2)

for i in new_data2:

    if 'VALUE' in i:
        print('found!')
```

Comment: turning `df` into a string is a bad idea. try `df[column_name].str.contains('VALUE')` on the column.

Comment: `new_data2` does not have `VALUE`. Did you check that?

Comment: `new_data2` has `VALUE`

Comment: @QuangHoang this also does not work

Answer (score 1):

For your `data2`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

result = df2.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('VALUE'))
```

gives `result`:

```
   spike-2  hey spke     no
0    False     False   True
1    False     False  False
```

You can see the result by the rows:

```
result.any(axis=1)

0    True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Or by the columns:

```
result.any()

spike-2     False
hey spke    False
no           True
dtype: bool
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: I want to get row (index or row values ) that contains `VALUE`.
Also, a lot of different rows can have the `VALUE`, so the code should return all rows that have the value.

One question, is there a way to do this without `lambda`?

Comment: In the code, `lambda` applies to columns, so if you don't have that many columns, you should be fine. `result[result.any(axis=1)].index` should give you the indexes of the rows that contain `VALUE`